# Can we control which alternative sites get suggested when something is marked as "off topic"?

Tags: discussion

I've marked something as off topic today, but this meta was the only suggestion in the list web sites to move the question to. Do we build up this list ourselves? If yes, what are some suggestions to put on there? I would think [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) should be on it. Any other ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you can discuss it in chat or on meta (here), so that we can learn and discuss the boundaries of our on-topic definitions.

Comment: What needs to be done is to have paths added. Mods can move something anywhere, others can only move it to a small list of designated sites. The default is only to the meta, but more can be added. They usually don't like to for beta sites, however...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this can be done, but we'll first have to establish the site and graduate out of beta. Only then will a permanent migration path be established. Until then, that option is not available for users.

The reason is that providing an option in the close menu is a way to let the community decide where to chuck it without a mod intervention. This is a very bad idea when a site is new and budding, because of a few reasons as below:

1. With all the initial activity and excitement, people are overenthusiastic in shipping things off to other sites. This might not actually be the right thing to do because we're still defining what's on topic for us and to what extent questions marginally outside our bounds will be tolerated. Also, we need questions!
2. Just because a question is more math/programming related doesn't necessarily mean it's on-topic there or a good quality question. The community has to grow to learn and understand which questions should be moved and which shouldn't. The golden rule of migration is "don't migrate crap".
3. You can close questions with *just 1 rep* in private beta. This means that a user, who has *no understanding* of the SE system, can vote to migrate a question elsewhere, possibly flooding that site with questions that are possibly off-topic there.
4. From what I've observed from other sites, a good number of the users who are active in the private beta and initial phase of public beta never make it to the end as dedicated users. We don't want good questions to be incorrectly shipped off by a small group of people w/o mod intervention, especially when the consensus of the larger community is yet unknown.
5. Some sites never make it *out of beta*, so providing a migration path to this site might result in certain questions dying when the site is shut down. So migration has to be done carefully and selectively.

So, the best thing to do right now is to flag it for a mod to migrate. In the initial days, the site is moderated by SE employees and they will not evaluate your flag unless a strong consensus builds up (i.e., a meta post with several in agreement or multiple flags). In a few weeks, they'll select pro-tem mods from the community who can gauge them better and they'll work with mods from the other sites in deciding if questions should be migrated.